# Array inside arraylist access

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to access a variable that is stores as part of an object that is in an array. However that array is in an arraylist. How can access that variable?
To make it clear, I have a car object that has speed. I placed 4 cars in an array. And that array is duplicated and put in an arraylist.

```
public int getSpeedOfCarA (int index) {//used to access the variable speed in an array
    return garage [index].getSpeed ();
     }
```

Now I was trying this but got stuck.

```
public int getSpeedOfCarB(int n){

carSpeeds.get(...); //not sure what to use here.
}
```

Comment: Presumably by iterating the `Car`(s) in the `List`... I assume `getSpeedOfCarA(int)` is in class `Car`, and also why do you need a `getSpeedOfCarB(int)`... what is that for?

Comment: Can you please post your full code?

Comment: the first is an array of cars from a car class. It has speed as a variable. The second should be an arraylist of arrays of cars.

Answer (score 4):

To access things inside of other things, simply chain the access syntax together. For the example of getting a field inside an object inside an array inside a `List`, you would simply use

```
list.get(pos)[arrayPos].fieldName
```

You may be misunderstanding how ArrayList works however: When working with it, you never see the array, and in fact as far as syntax is concerned it doesn't matter whether it's implemented as an Array or as a LinkedList or whatever else. If so, you need not use any array operator, as the `get` method will do that for you:

```
list.get(pos).fieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use an Iterator to access the car object in the list.

```
ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
Iterator i = list.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    Car car = i.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
for(Car[] carArrays : listOfCarArrays) {
    for (Car car : carArrays) {
        //do something with car like car.getSpeed();
    }
}
```